# What does "stereotyping" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, nouns

I'm interested in understanding the following paragraph:

> I’m stereotyping when I say that the Chinese can’t drive for shit.
>   They just can’t, and that’s that.

The word *stereotype* is a new one to me and I looked it up in the dictionary. I've read all the explanations but still not sure I've understood it. Does it mean that guy is unjustified when saying *Chinese can't drive*? Or does it mean the guy just literally says *Chinese can't drive*?

Comment: You've missed an important piece of context. That clause starts ***ain’t nobody telling me** I’m stereotyping when I say...* In this context, *ain't nobody telling me* = *it isn't true that*. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of phrasing this is:

> I am *using a stereotype* when I say the Chinese can't drive for shit.

A stereotype is:

> A set idea that people have about what someone or something is like, especially an idea that is wrong ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stereotype))

They have changed the noun *stereotype* into a verb form.  This is called *[gerund](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gerund)ing* (See what I did there?)

As 1006a points out, the entire phrase is:

> Ain’t nobody telling me I’m stereotyping when I say that the Chinese can’t drive for shit. They just can’t, and that’s that.

---

This is saying that people may say they are being stereotypical in saying *the Chinese can’t drive for shit*, (as it is arguable that while some may not be able to, [some are likely to be proficient drivers](https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/races/2017/China.html)) but they are arguing that they are not being stereotypical, and asserting it is a fact.

This is ironic since despite by denying being stereotypical, they are admitting to their stereotype.